# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't cleanup properly in try/catch block

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Consider the following code :

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void FuncA(){}

void FuncB(std::function<void()> callback) {
  try {
    // Do something here...
  }
  catch(...) {
    return FuncA();
  }

  // Do something else...
}

void main() {
  auto foo = std::make_shared<bool>();
  auto callback = [foo]{};

  std::cout << foo.use_count() << std::endl;
  FuncB(callback);
  std::cout << foo.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

When compiling this under Visual Studio 2013, the generated assembly code for FuncB() doesn't cleanup the callback properly, which increases the reference count of foo by 1 and causes a memory leak.

One thing I did notice, is if I change FuncB to be...

```
void FuncB(std::function<void()> callback) {
  try {
    // Do something here...
  }
  catch(...) {
    FuncA();
    return;
  }

  // Do something else...
}
```

... then everything works as expected and the count before and after are the same.

I'm using VS2013 version 12.0.31101.00 update 4
Compiler version is 18.00.31101 x64.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this issue ?

Comment: Looks like tail call optimisation might've messed something up in the problematic version.

Comment: Does the same problem happen in the latest VS2015 community? That would be a very telling test.

Comment: [Works as expected](http://rextester.com/VRNMO51268) with VC15, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example in both MSVC 2013 Update 4, MSVC 2015 Update 2 and Coliru (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

In MSVC 2013 I got the output:

```
2
3
```

While in MSVC 2015 I got the output:

```
2
2
```

Coliru confirms MSVC 2015's output, so it seems to be a bug in MSVC 2013.

I would either upgrade compiler if possible, or use:

```
FuncA();
return;
```

I consider it slightly odd to return void and would prefer the return statement on the next line anyway. (But that is just my opinion.)

Comment: Actually you could use a function that returns an integer and still experience the same behavior.

Comment: I have noticed that this problem does not occur if the `try { }` block contains a `return;` statement. Is this true for you too?